# Accessing database that is running inside a docker container?

Tags: node.js, database, docker, containers

I have a MariaDB up and running in a Docker container. I want to know how to connect to it from an app running locally (not) in the docker container. How can I open up access?

Answer (score 1):

your MariaDB container must publish ports, and you will connect using those ports. See for example http://amattn.com/p/installing_maria_db_mysql_with_docker.html

the port 3306 in the container will be mapped to a port on the host, and you will connect to that port.

Comment: I read through this. The part that confused me was sudo docker run -v="$HOME/mysqldata":"/data"  -i -t -p 3306 <YOU>/mariadb55 /bin/bash. Do I need to mount this?

Comment: By default your container has 10GB of disk space, which may not be enough, so, yes this is useful

Answer (score 1):

when you call docker run to start your container you can bind a specific port like this

```
docker run -p your_port:3306
```

this will make your container accessible on docker_host_ip:your_port and the docker service will take care of forwarding the connection to the right container at the port 3306

Comment: I did the following: docker run -p 5506:3306 -dit mycont/ubuntumaria:0.2 and ensured the db was running with docker exec 4a43548a68ba /etc/init.d/mysql start. However, after plugging in the host IP and 5506, I can't get a connection...

Comment: suppose you checked docker ps -a to see if it was running fine? What does it say when you try to connect? A simple timeout?

Comment: I also executed docker exec fcd12bf1da81 /etc/init.d/mysql status and see that it is running

Comment: You can try to create a container from a  simpler image (say mysql:latest) with a port and ping that to see if it works, just to reduce the places where the problem could be... cant think of anything else sry